# Authenticate client windows user using ldap weblogic security

Tags: java, oracle-adf, weblogic11g

i try to Authenticate windows user  to  got the client windows log in user from  this :::: request.getremoteuser()

i get my LDap users on weblogic but after that i got lost

can any one help me 
thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I totally understand your problem, but it looks like you are trying to use Single Sign On (SSO) for authentication.

If that's the case, SSO configuration on weblogic is a bit of a challenge, there are several configuration options available depending of LDAP implementation you are using (MS Active Directory or OAM).

This topic is too complex to be solved with answering a forum question, but all we can do for you is to point to into the right direction.

For Active Directory, you can check this blog:
http://biemond.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/single-sign-on-with-windows-kerberos-on.html

For Oracle Access Manager, here are some guidelines for you:
https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/adf_oam